# how to keep properties file outside the mule code in mulesoft

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

i have defined a dev.properties file for the mule flow.where i am passing the username and password required to run the flow.This password gets updated everymonth.So everymonth i have to deploy the code to the server after changing the password.Is there a way , where we can keep the properties file outside the code in mule server path.and change it when required in order to avoid redeployment.

Answer (score 1):

One more idea is to completely discard any usage of a file to pickup the username and password.

Instead try using a `credentials providing service`, like a http requestor which is collecting the username and password from an independent API(child API/providing service).

Store it in a cache object-store of your parent API (the calling API). Keep using those values, unless the flow using them fails or if the client needs to expire them after a month. Later simply refresh them.

You can trigger your credentials providing service using a scheduler with a Cron expression having *Monthly Triggers*.

Answer (score 0):

No, because even if the properties file is outside the application, properties are loaded on application deployment. So you would need to restart the application anyway to pick up the new values.

Instead you can create a custom module that read the properties from somewhere (a file, some service, etc), assign the value to a variable, and use the variable instead at execution time. Note that some configurations may only be set at deployment time, so variables will not be evaluated as such.

Comment: Yes. It is better way to keep properties outside of the app. Read properties from the file system. At least you don't have to rebuild app every month. In theory yoiu should only change property file and restart app. However, in practice, I do not know why, when I simply restart it picks old properties. Maybe from some cache, who knows. It's a real bummer. What I do - I restart whole server or redploy (but the same jar file) this one particluar app. Maybe @aled knows why it happens. I don't.

Answer (score 0):

If the credentials are not exposing your application security or data, then you can move them to another config file(place it Outside mule app path). Generate a RAML file which will read & reload the credentials after application deploy/start-up, and store them in cache with timeToLive around 12 hours.
The next time when you have to change Username/Password, change in the file directly and cache will refresh it automatically after expiry time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually not because all the properties secure properties needs to be there at runtime and is it is not there your application will get failed,
There is one way but it’s not best one, instead of editing code you can directly edit secure property I.e username and password in your case directly in cloudhub runtime manager properties tab.
After editing just apply changes then api will restart automatically and will deploy successfully